# TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigationState.index')

Tags: react-native

i have this error shown but i don't know why :

> [15:52:26] TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'props.navigationState.index')
>
> This error is located at:
>       in tabBarComponent (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:72)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:102)
>       in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
>       in NavigationView (created by Navigator)
>       in Navigator (created by SceneView)
>       in SceneView (at DrawerView.js:149)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:20)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:16)
>       in ResourceSavingScene (at DrawerView.js:148)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at screens.native.js:83)
>       in ScreenContainer (at DrawerView.js:138)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:153)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at DrawerLayout.js:323)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:153)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at DrawerLayout.js:322)
>       in Handler (at DrawerLayout.js:358)
>       in DrawerLayout (at DrawerView.js:161)
>       in DrawerView (created by Navigator)
>       in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
>       in NavigationContainer (at routes.js:42)
>       in _class (at App.js:53)
>       in Provider (at App.js:52)
>       in App (at registerRootComponent.js:17)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:16)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
>
> This error is located at:
>       in NavigationContainer (at routes.js:42)
>       in _class (at App.js:53)
>       in Provider (at App.js:52)
>       in App (at registerRootComponent.js:17)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:16)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
>   * src/modules/BoardScreen/index.js:21:58 in tabBarComponent
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12020:22
>   in mountIndeterminateComponent
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16075:21
>   in performUnitOfWork
>   - ... 14 more stack frames from framework internals

it's in this line of code in :

```
                            active={props.navigationState.index === 0}
```

my index.js is like this :

```
export default (MainScreenNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Tasks: { screen: Tasks },
        Members: { screen: Members },
        Chat: { screen: Chat }
    },
    {
        tabBarPosition: "bottom",
        tabBarComponent: props => {
            return (
                <Footer>
                    <FooterTab>
                        <Button
                            vertical
                            active={props.navigationState.index === 0}
                            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Tasks")}>
                            <Icon name="bookmarks" />
                            <Text>Tasks</Text>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            vertical
                            active={props.navigationState.index === 1}
                            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Members")}>
                            <Icon name="people" />
                            <Text>Members</Text>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            vertical
                            active={props.navigationState.index === 2}
                            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Chat")}>
                            <Icon name="git-branch" />
                            <Text>Chat</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </FooterTab>
                </Footer>
            );
        }
    }
));
```

can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [react navigation's custom navigators docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#navigation-state) it should be `props.navigation.state.index`